# how to make double quote to accepted by facebook feed post

Tags: android

friend's
   I need help on posting the feed in facebook when string contains double quote,at the time facebook haven't accepting..
for example if the content is something like this,
 **Help on posting "feed" in facebook for android.**

suppose i need to post above at the time the feed title is getting null because of double quotes,how can i replace it with the same i have to post.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what format you're using to send it, and I've not messed with the Facebook API myself, but I would just try replacing the quotes with `&quot;` and see if that works.

Comment: hi..i'm getting the above what u said above with &quote being replaced but the needed character to be not displayed has " insted it shows &quote;

Comment: actaully i used &quot; only but it dispalys the same only but it displays &quot; in my output.

Comment: Can you post your code? Also, are you escaping the quotes, i.e. `\"` rather than `"`?